# Unix - Choosing Random from Table Arrays in Unix

Tags: unix, sh

I'm trying to choose random data from a table and print it, here's how I would imagine it to be:

```
Ids = {"1","2","3"}

echo $(($RANDOM % $Ids))
```

Though I'm getting an error, am I not doing this right?

Comment: If the shell supports it, try: `echo ${Ids[$RANDOM % ${#Ids}]}`

Comment: In what shell does `Ids = {...}` create an array?

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating the array correctly.  *If* the shell you are using supports it, you might be able to do:

```
Ids=( 1 2 3 )
echo "${Ids[$RANDOM % ${#Ids}]}"
```

Note that you use `()` to create an array and there must not be any whitespace around `=`.  When you write `$Ids`, that gives you the first element of the array, so `$(( $RANDOM % $Ids ))` is computing `$RANDOM % 0`, so I imagine you're getting errors like `28072 % 0: division by 0`  It would help if, instead of the nondescript "I'm getting an error", you specified what error you get.

Comment: I'm getting 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected' when trying to run it as sh

Comment: @Happy `sh` does not even support arrays.

Comment: `sh` doesn't support `$RANDOM` either, for that matter. You need to use a specific shell that supports both, `bash` for example.